# Armature Copy transformations Constraint Options in Blank

Tags: constraints

A Little help here pls...

I made a COpy transformations constraint between 2 bones from diferent armatures and it has no options to customize.. help pls

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the bone that you've added the transformation to in Pose Mode and go to bone constraints in the properties editor to see the constraint's properties.

[image: Bone constraints]